# Is there an error with this IF statement? (Windows batch)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

So here is the odd thing.  These IF statements:

```
if "%option%"=="1" goto 1-1
if "%option%"=="2" goto 1-2
if "%option%"=="3" goto 1-3
```

DO WORK.

However, these IF statements:

```
if "%option%"=="eat" goto eat
if "%option%"=="drink" goto drink
if "%option%"=="sleep" goto sleep
if "%option%"=="suicide" goto suicide
if "%option%"=="stats" goto stats
```

DO NOT.

I know using more than one character is possible, because it works at the beginning of the prompt in these if statements:

```
if "%startgame%"=="how2play" goto how2play
if "%startgame%"=="play" goto play
```

Any idea why only the numbers are working and not the words?

Comment: It probably has something to do with something you're not showing us.

Comment: Could it be a case sensitivity issue?  Try `if /i`.  If that doesn't help, turn echo on and see where your script starts to drift sideways.  It might not be the `if` statements.

Comment: Or you may already have quotes in your variable value, which would cause mismatches.